# aws-cli command in windows to get the latest object from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, tail

I am using a command using aws cli in my windows machine to  get latest file from s3 bucket .

```
aws s3 ls s3://Bucket-name --recursive | sort |tail -n 1
```

It is listing all the files in sorted manner according to date upto here:

```
aws s3 ls s3://Bucket-name --recursive | sort
```

But writing the full command throws error:

> 'Tail is not recognized as an internal or external command'.

Is there some other alternative for tail or for the full command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS CLI permits [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) expressions in the `--query` parameter.

This command shows the most recently-updated object:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

It's basically saying:

- Sort by `LastModified`
- Obtain the last `[-1]` entry
- Show the Key (filename)